# Which background model to run

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an application which will require a service to
run in the background. I am relatively new to android programming,
and after reading many posts, blogs, how-to's and books on creating
and managing services, I am still pretty confused about which model I
should try to use.

First, let me present (in general) the application requirements: I
need an application which will spawn a background process (service?)
which will connect to a bluetooth device. The bluetooth device is
designed to deliver data to the android device. The issue is that the
data could come in at any moment, so the bluetooth connection has to
stay active.  Note that the application is a VERY SPECIFIC app and is
NOT intended for public use.  I do understand the arguments for not
having background apps running all the time, but please understand
that this is a very specific application for a very specific client.

Now, in general, I think the program flow would be to start the
application (and launch a UI activity). Then I need to configure and
connect to the bluetooth device.  At this point, the user should be
able to do other things - make phone calls, check their email, etc.,
while the bluetooth connection is still active and potentially
receiving data.  If data comes in, a notification is fired, etc.

So here are my questions and concerns:

1. If I start an app (which spawns a UI activity and ultimately my
   bluetooth connection service) but the app is killed, apparently, the
   service handling the bluetooth connection is killed as well.  How can
   I keep that alive?  I read that Service.setForeground() was
   depricated, but even if I were to set it to the foreground, if the app
   is killed, the service is killed as well.  I need to have it run in
   the background with as high of a priority as possible (again, I do
   understand that this is considered "bad form", but this is a specific
   app and this functionality has been requested by the client).
2. If I started the app (and the service, etc.), but the user, say,
   answers a phone call, the app is put into the background.  However,
   let's say the user goes back to the home screen and starts a DIFFERENT
   instance of the app, i.e., he doesn't hold down the home key to select
   the already running app from the task manager but starts a completely
   new one.  If the service handling the bluetooth connection is still
   running, how will this new instance behave?  i.e., how can I get it to
   connect to the bluetooth service which is ALREADY running in the FIRST
   instance of the app instead of this new instance?  Do I have to use
   some form of a Remote service instead of a local service?  This is
   where I'm a little confused by things as it seems remote services and
   defining an AIDL seems to create a lot of extra overhead, and since
   I'm already creating a lot of overhead with the service running in the
   background all the time, I want to keep that as small as possible.
   How can I insure I am connecting to the same service already running?

Answer (score 4):

1)
The service does not depend on an `Activity`. You can have it running on the background until you call `stopSelf()`.

You can have a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that listens to the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` so your service is started when the phone is turned on.

2)
Your `Activity` should bind to the service. And get the info from it.
Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814375/service-bind-to-an-activity).